# warning: attempt to present

Tags: ios, storyboard, warnings, call, hierarchy

my problem is that when I call the function:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"FinalPlayPT" sender: self];
```

it works but I have this warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I'am using storyboard, xcode 4.5.2 and iOS6, any ideas? Thanks.

By the way, if I use a UIButton for the segue, there is no warning, but I need to do it programmatically.

I've been trying all the was to call another VC and always the same warning.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: We need a little more information... Where exactly are you trying to call this method?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are trying to perform your segue before your view controller is on screen. Move your call to `viewDidAppear:` or later.